# Setting PYTHONPATH for compiled QGIS version on Linux

Tags: pyqgis

I'm trying to set the PYTHONPATH in order to be able to load the qgis classes in a python console (not the QGIS Python one).

I followed some resources I've found ([PYQGIS Cookbook](http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/intro.html#running-custom-applications), and others) but I get still the same error message:

```
>>> import qgis.core
ImportError: No module named qgis.core
```

I'm pretty sure the problem is that I have a compiled version of QGIS and of course the PATHs suggested are different.

The folder of my QGIS is:

```
/home/user/QGIS-master
```

I tried to add the following to the `.bashrc` file in order to have the PATH but nothing changed (still the error of above):

```
export PYTHONPATH=/home/user/QGIS-master/python/
```

Someone has an idea of which is the correct PATH I have to export?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The folder for the PYTHONPATH must be the compiled one and not the source one. Your build path should be something like `/home/user/QGIS-master/<builddir>/output/`. I am guessing you are running from build your QGIS version so you just export the  environment var like:

`export PYTHONPATH=/home/user/QGIS-master/<builddir>/output/python/`

maybe it also could be necessary to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH (as mentioned in PyQGIS Cookbook).

`export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/user/QGIS-master/<builddir>/output/lib/`